# "\bibsection undefined" when using elsarticle?

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

When using the elsarticle class, I get an error saying "\bibsection undefined". The error doesn't appear when I use the standard, "article" document class.

Additionally, I get two errors regarding the hyperref.sty package ("\Argument of \x has an extra }" and "Paragraph ended before \x was complete"). These two errors also aren't there when I use other document classes.

Here is the MWE for my file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false, breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false, hidelinks]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
 \usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{lscape}
\setstretch{1.5}
\makeatletter

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{lmr} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
   \SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr}{b}{n}
   \SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
   \SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\bibliographystyle{authoryear}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black}
\begin{frontmatter}{}

\title{xyz}

\author{xy}

\address{xyz}

\ead{xyz@gmail.com}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent \textbf{Classification}: lalala
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
\noindent Lalala
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}{}

Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea about how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: It would help *greatly* if you could show us a small, yet complete document that reproduces the errors you mention here. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to provide a lot more information, preferably in the form of a minimal document that produces the issues you wish to fix. Please also refrain from needless hyperbole, such as "The error doesn't happen when I use any other document class"; there are hundreds, if not thousands, of LaTeX document classes out there, and I hence don't think you actually meant what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you both! I edited the post and posted a MWE. Hopefully this will somehow suffice - apologies for the styling, I am complete rookie here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can format code blocks by indenting it with four spaces or clicking the `{}` button. The code contains a lot of packages. Do you really need all of them? In general it is a very good idea to use a few packages as possible.

Comment: Fixed the problem! Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: If you solved the issue, please post an answer below (and accept it) so others can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 3):

The error about `\x` is due to `pdfusetitle`, because `hyperref` assumes a standard definition of `\title` and `\author`, but `elsarticle` changes them.

Since `elsarticle` is meant for submissions to Elsevier journals, I don't think you should load packages that change the layout. In particular font packages, `tocbibind`, `geometry`, `fancyhdr` and `setspace`.

Note that `breakurl` and `fixltx2e` are useless and should be removed.

Such a long list of packages probably contains several that aren't needed for the specific document.

Also `hyperref` should be loaded *last*, with the exception of `bookmark` (and some others that aren't called here).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by removing some the packages I was using - too many, I know it's a bad habit.

In particular, `elsarticle` already includes the main `hyperref` options so that all of the `\usepackage{hyperref}` lines were unnecessary, which fixed the second issue (the `hyperref` errors).

The first issue (the bibsection error) was fixed by removing the `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` line.

Many thanks to moewe and Mico for their kind help. Best.